# Busy-waiting Future in Rust Tokio

Tags: rust, rust-tokio, busy-waiting

I want to implement a Future that busy-waits on its completion.

According to [this link](https://tokio.rs/tokio/tutorial/async#a-few-loose-ends), this is one option

```
impl Future for Delay {
    type Output = &'static str;

    fn poll(self: Pin<&mut Self>, cx: &mut Context<'_>)
        -> Poll<&'static str>
    {
        if Instant::now() >= self.when {
            println!("Hello world");
            Poll::Ready("done")
        } else {
            // Ignore this line for now.
            cx.waker().wake_by_ref();
            Poll::Pending
        }
    }
}
```

What I am worried about is this future starving out other tasks. Is it guaranteed that if I call wake inside the Future that returns Pending, that this wake will execute as a last item after epol, timers, and any other wakes called before?

Is this the good way to implement busy-wait Future?

Comment: This is probably very specific to the async runtime you're using.

Comment: what mean "busy-wait" for you ?

Comment: you may be interest by https://docs.rs/tokio/latest/tokio/task/fn.yield_now.html

Comment: @Stargateur I have seen that one, especially the non-guarantees section…

Comment: By busy wait I mean checking the condition in infinite loop until it is true without context switches or interrupts

Comment: if you can't meet the non guarantee well async is not what you should use.